# how can I change user permission settings for an application

Tags: chmod

I am trying to prevent the guest user from accessing software-center (I know it can't install anything, but I don't even want it to browse)

The file is owned by root and in group root.

I run: `sudo chmod o= /usr/bin/software-center`

Afterwards I run `ls -l` and get the following output:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Sep 10 14:28 /usr/bin/software-center -> ../share software-    center/software-center`

The first part of the output indicates chmod didn't do anything and the second part I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want root user to have access to the software center, you will need to change the 'other' access to the file /usr/share/software-center

```
sudo chmod 750 /usr/share/software-center
```

If you want to restore access to software center for your user you can change the group for the file /usr/share/software-center to your group:

```
sudo chown root:username /usr/share/software-center
```

this will result in only root and you having access.

If you want other users to also have access, you can make a group for this purpose, eg 'install' and make the group access 'install', and add any users you want to give access to this group.

As pointed out, /usr/bin/software-center is a link, not the actual file so you can't change its permissions

Answer (score 1):

From `man chmod`

> chmod  never  changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a problem since the permissions of symbolic links are never used.  However,  for
>          each  symbolic  link  listed on the command line, chmod changes the permissions of the pointed-to file.
>          In contrast, chmod ignores symbolic links encountered during recursive directory traversals.

Check the permissions of the target instead: `ll /usr/share/software-center/software-center`.